# Making an image visible with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys, so what I want to do is make an `img` visible (at the start it is invisible) with a JS function.
Here is the code:

```
for(k = 0; k < advent.getDate(); k++) {
    if(adventSonntagDate[k] <= advent.getDate()) {
        // I'm pretty sure the line below is somehow wrong.
         document.getElementById("f" + (k + 1)).style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
```

So the div(s) are formatted like this in CSS:

```
.flamme01 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    left: 277px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The IDs are f1, f2, f3 and f4. After calling the function which contains the `for` loop with a button nothing happens. The pictures don't appear. The rest of the code should be OK. I "debugged" it with `alert()` showing me the vars etc. while running.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

your for loop initalizer is `k` not `i`

should be

```
document.getElementById("f"+(k+1)).style.visibility='visible';
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("f"+(i+1)).style.visibility='visible';
///-------problem is this----^
```

Comment: it's need to know which value is coming by `adventSonntagDate[k]`, Can you see that by `console.log(adventSonntagDate[k]);`

Comment: 7 and 14 it should return the advent sundays(dont know if u understand what i mean these are the 4 sundays before christmas in my language) that already "happend" until the date i entered in a drop down list

Comment: and should light candles(display images) based on the number of sundays

Comment: At this point you need to show your complete html, css and javascript at jsfiddle not provided as earlier.

Comment: somehow it started working... didnt really change anything important... sorry for wasting your time and thx for showing me console.log i think this is going to be great for the future

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear. If you just want to display some elements based on some condition, you can change the display none to block. I just created a jsfiddle for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/9wuVs/

```
for(var i=1;i<=4;i++){
    document.getElementById('f'+i).style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: already tried it with display none and block still dont working

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle with your problem. I see that you are giving style to .flamme01 and you are checking for f1, f2,... That doesn't make sense. I am guessing that, you have given this classname to all these divs. Then, what will advent.getDate() will give?

Comment: advent.getDate() will return me a number between 0-4 and what i want is to display f1 if i get 1, f1 and f2 if i get 1,2 etc... http://jsfiddle.net/5px5H/1/ thats an easier version of my function and i have an idea could it be a problem if there is another picture behind the hidden ones. could this cause them to not appear

Comment: to answer my own question the background pic isnt the problem

Answer (score 0):

I beliewe that you need not (i+1) in wrong line, because you iterate 'k' value, not 'i'.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(k=0;k<advent.getDate();k++) {

    if(adventSonntagDate[k]<=advent.getDate()) {
        //Im pretty sure the line below is somehow wrong.
         document.getElementById("f"+(k+1)).style.visibility='visible';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

m just guessing it may be that its failing because the date is looking for an Id too high to work and so the script is crashing

```
alert('hello');
```

just before the visibility line, does it ever fire?

Answer (score -1):

[Try using display](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Also check your code to see if the Javascript is running before the css, inside the head tag.

Comment: already tried display not working too and my script is called before my stylesheet

Comment: It has to be running after, the css is overwriting the javascript.